# Current Android font

Tags: fonts, themes

Several months ago, I changed my base font using Font Installer. Now I can't remember the name of the font I changed to. Is there a simple way to find out?

Comment: Why don’t you attach a screenshot of your font? I might be able to recognize it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the name of the font you have changed to, you can use the website [What the Font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont).

Comment: That's a great tool, thanks! But there must be some way to figure out what it is via Android....

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to find a textarea where you can input big text, and then just take a screenshot and upload it to What the Font. That's probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

If you merely *changed* the font, then you can simply look at `/etc/system_fonts.xml` to see which font it's set to use. If you have a good file manager and a good text editor, then you can just browse to the file and look. You might need to make a copy on your SD card and rename the copy to end in `.txt`.

If you actually *replaced* a system font file, then you'll need to parse the TrueType file. Unless you get lucky with finding the right app, the format's too complex to parse for a simple Android-only answer. The next best thing is to copy the file to your computer (either via file manager + USB storage connection or pulling the font file with `adb pull /system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf`) and try seeing if your OS includes a decent font preview/install program. Or you can use the Unix strings utility (probably only on your phone if you have BusyBox installed) like `strings /system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf`.

Note that `Roboto-Regular.ttf` is the default font as of Android 4.x. Earlier versions use `DroidSans.ttf` instead.